# Duplicate Entry

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Why does the following generate duplicate entries for Strategy & Segment? Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
public ActionResult Create(Program program)
{
    db.Programs.Add(program);

    Strategy strategy = db.Strategies.Where(s => s.Name == program.Strategy.Name).SingleOrDefault();
    Segment segment = db.Segments.Where(m => m.Name == program.Segment.Name).SingleOrDefault();

    // Make sure not to save duplicate entries of segment & strategy
    if (strategy != null)
    {
        program.Strategy = strategy;
        db.Entry(strategy).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }

    if (segment != null)
    {
        program.Segment = segment;
        db.Entry(segment).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 db.Entry(strategy).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

and

```
 db.Entry(segment).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Comment: How do you initialise your DBContext? Try initialising it in this method?

Comment: Solved, I moved the call to db.Programs.Add(program); just prior SaveChanges().